# Where in the java files do i find the reference of the tick i have circled in blue?

Tags: android, android-studio

[i would like to know where in the java files i find reference of that tick](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pnaaX.jpg)

I want to add a date picker function such that when i click the tick to add a certain task to the bucket list then it will show the date that task was created.

Answer (score 0):

in drawable folder, and in menu/menu_add_edit_task.xml

Comment: What is the name

Comment: can you take a screenshot of menu_add_edit_task.xml?

Comment: if you can, show me how to add the date and time picker fuction

Comment: click Ctrl+Shift+F and search for @+id/action_save 
that is the item with tick. If you need drawable, look few lines bellow that, under "android:icon="

Comment: can i send you the whole project to your email so that you can help

Comment: Are you still there?

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.tanakadanielphiri.zjutbucketlist.features.addEdit;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import com.tanakadanielphiri.zjutbucketlist.R;
import com.tanakadanielphiri.zjutbucketlist.models.Task;
import com.getkeepsafe.taptargetview.TapTarget;
import com.getkeepsafe.taptargetview.TapTargetView;
import butterknife.BindView;
import butterknife.ButterKnife;
import io.realm.Realm;

public class AddEditActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String TASK_ID = "taskID";
    private static final String PREF_TUTO_KEY = "prefTuto";

    private Realm realm;
    private AddEditPresenter presenter;
    private ActionBar ab;

    @BindView(R.id.toolbar) Toolbar toolbar;
    @BindView(R.id.container) ConstraintLayout container;
    @BindView(R.id.titleEt) EditText titleEt;
    @BindView(R.id.contentEt) EditText contentEt;
    @BindView(R.id.priority) AppCompatSpinner priority;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_edit);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();

        // Setup the priorities spinner
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.priorities, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        priority.setAdapter(adapter);

        // Setup the toolbar
        toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_add_edit_task);
        ab = getSupportActionBar();

        // Setup the presenter
        presenter = new AddEditPresenter(this, realm);
        presenter.displayTask(getIntent().getStringExtra(TASK_ID));

        // Show the tutorial
        if (!getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getBoolean(PREF_TUTO_KEY, false)) {
            showTutorial();
        }
    }

    public void showTutorial() {
        TapTargetView.showFor(this,
                TapTarget.forToolbarMenuItem(toolbar,
                        R.id.action_save, getString(R.string.save_your_changes),
                        getString(R.string.dont_forget_to_save_your_changes))
                        .dimColor(R.color.primaryText)
                        .drawShadow(true));
        getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putBoolean(PREF_TUTO_KEY, true).apply();
    }

    public void setupView(Task task) {
        if (ab != null) {
            ab.setTitle(task == null ? getString(R.string.add_task) : getString(R.string.edit_task));
            ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }

        if (task != null) {
            titleEt.setText(task.getTitle());
            contentEt.setText(task.getContent());
            priority.setSelection(task.getPriority());
        }
    }

    public void showError(String err) {
        Snackbar.make(container, err, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    public void goBack() {
        onBackPressed();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_add_edit_task, menu);

        if (!presenter.hasTask()) {
            menu.removeItem(R.id.action_delete);
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                onBackPressed();
                break;
            case R.id.action_save:
                presenter.saveTask(titleEt.getText().toString(), contentEt.getText().toString(), priority.getSelectedItemPosition());
                break;
            case R.id.action_delete:
                presenter.deleteTask();
                break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        realm.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.tanakadanielphiri.zjutbucketlist.features.addEdit.AddEditActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        tools:text="Title"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/titleEt"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textColor="@color/primaryText"
        android:hint="@string/task_title"
        android:nextFocusDown="@+id/contentEt"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/priority"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        tools:text="My super content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/contentEt"
        android:textColor="@color/secondaryText"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:hint="@string/what_do_you_need_to_do"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/titleEt"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/titleEt"
        android:id="@+id/priority" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```